# Go: Removing accents from strings

Tags: go

I'm new to Go and I'm trying to implement a function to convert accented characters into their non-accented equivalent. I'm attempting to follow the example given in [this](http://blog.golang.org/normalization) blog (see the heading 'Performing magic').

What I've attempted to gather from this is:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "unicode"
    "bytes"
    "code.google.com/p/go.text/transform"
    "code.google.com/p/go.text/unicode/norm"
)


func isMn (r rune) bool {
        return unicode.Is(unicode.Mn, r) // Mn: nonspacing marks
    }

func main() {
    r := bytes.NewBufferString("Your Śtring")
    t := transform.Chain(norm.NFD, transform.RemoveFunc(isMn), norm.NFC)
    r = transform.NewReader(r, t)
    fmt.Println(r)
}
```

It does not work in the slightest and I quite honestly don't know what it means anyway. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

r should be or type `io.Reader`, and you can't print r like that. First, you need to read the content to a byte slice:

```
 var (   
         s = "Your Śtring"
         b = make([]byte, len(s))

         r io.Reader = strings.NewReader(s)
 ) 
 t := transform.Chain(norm.NFD, transform.RemoveFunc(isMn), norm.NFC)
 r = transform.NewReader(r, t)
 r.Read(b)
 fmt.Println(string(b))
```

This works, but for some reason it returns me "Your Stri", two bytes less than needed.

This here is the version which actually does what you need, but I'm still not sure why the example from the blog works so strangely.

```
s := "Yoùr Śtring"
b := make([]byte, len(s))

t := transform.Chain(norm.NFD, transform.RemoveFunc(isMn), norm.NFC)
_, _, e := t.Transform(b, []byte(s), true)
if e != nil { panic(e) }

fmt.Println(string(b))
```

Comment: Note, although `transform.NewReader` (or `transform.NewWriter`) are preferred if there is any way to "stream" the data (e.g. to transform data while reading/write from/to a file or the network), if you only want to deal with an existing `[]byte` or `string`, the transform package also provides [`transform.Bytes`](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/text/transform/#Bytes) and [`transform.String`](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/text/transform/#String).

Comment: Directly calling the transform method like this isn't a good idea!

Comment: The reason you get fewer bytes than you expect is that you are not reading everything from the reader. The easiest "fix" to your existing code is to replace the read call with `io.ReadFull(r, b)`, but that still makes assumptions about the ending length, there are better ways to do this.

Answer (score 22):

Note that Go 1.5 (August 2015) or Go 1.6 (Q1 2016) could introduce a new **runes** package, with transform operations.

That includes (in [`runes/example_test.go`](https://go-review.googlesource.com/#/c/8336/5/runes/example_test.go)) a `runes.Remove` function, which will help transform `résumé` into `resume`:

```
func ExampleRemove() {
    t := transform.Chain(norm.NFD, runes.Remove(runes.In(unicode.Mn)), norm.NFC)
    s, _, _ := transform.String(t, "résumé")
    fmt.Println(s)

    // Output:
    // resume
}
```

This is [still being reviewed though (April 2015)](https://go-review.googlesource.com/#/c/8336/).

Answer (score 0):

I think this should always work:

```golang
string(norm.NFD.String(char)[0])
```